# Type of parameters of a parametric family of probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

A statistical parameter is a quantity that indexes a family of probability distributions.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_parameter) has the following definition of a shape parameter:

> A shape parameter is any parameter of a probability distribution that is neither a location parameter nor a scale parameter (nor a function of either or both of these only, such as a rate parameter). Such a parameter must affect the shape of a distribution rather than simply shifting it (as a location parameter does) or stretching/shrinking it (as a scale parameter does).

Therefore we have only four types (classes/categories) of parameters of a parametric family:

- location parameters
- scale parameters
- shape parameters
- functions of location and/or scale (such as rate parameter = $\frac{1}{\text{scale}}$)

If so I have the following questions:

What is the type of parameters which we call "degrees of freedom" (for example, parameter $k$ of the Chi-squared distribution $\chi^2(k)$) ?
What is the type of parameters $n$ and $p$ of the Binomial distribution $\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ ?

Comment: What is meant by "type" of a parameter? It looks like the wiki article just lumps all others not functions of location/scale parameters, and calls them all "shape parameters". By that definition $k,n,p$ would be shape parameters.

Comment: @coffeemath Here the word "type" means category, class, etc. The problem is that I have never heard something about type of parameters like $k,n,p$.